# The Loop for my theme with static front page is not working

Tags: loop

I'm developing a wordpress theme that uses a static page as front page.

My wordpress is configured to use "Home" page as its front_page and "Blog" page to show the blog posts.

When i try to use the loop on my "Blog" page to list the posts i get a odd behavior, the loop runs fine but any method to get the post information returns an empty string.

Sample code:

```
if (have_posts()) {
  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $posts[$index] = array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'permalink' => get_permalink(get_the_ID()),
                'content' => get_the_content(),
                'day' => get_the_date('j'),
                'month' => get_the_date('M')
                );
    $index++;

  }
}
```

If i have 5 posts that yould return me an array with 5 elements, all of them with empty strings as the values.

If i add `query_posts('posts_per_page=5');`. it works, but that shouldn't be needed.

What am i missing?

You can check the complete source code on github: https://github.com/albertein/coltsintheme

Thank you

*UPDATE*:
Even if i avoid using a static page as front page (delete front-page.php and configure wp con Settings>Reaging) I'm getting the same results which seems weird to me, it seems I'm missing something.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason that you're adding *another* abstraction layer on top of the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)? Such unnecessary complexity often leads to these sorts of issues. Is there any reason you can't rename `blog.php` as `home.php`, and rename `main.php` as `front-page.php`, and just let WordPress handle the template laoding? (Also: your `index.php` won't work outside of the Front Page and the Blog Posts Index. Is this be design?

Comment: You are also using short-tags in your code `<?` should be `<?php`

Comment: @ChipBennett Even if i use strictly the template hierarchy (Moving blog to home and main to front-page) I'm getting the same behavior. index.php doesn't do anything else because i was waiting to solve this issue to avoid to construct a custom query on every page to make it work.

Comment: @ChipBennett i uploaded the code that follows wordpress template hierarchy to github, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before the snippet i posted i was doing something like `$posts = array();`, it seems that wordpress keeps the collection of the posts to be used on the loop in a variable of the same name, so i was meesing with the data, just changed `$posts` for `$items` and now works fine.